# How is Turbojet defined by the FAA?

Tags: faa-regulations

During my commercial ground school today, we were asked if turbojet and turboprop aircraft are defined differently by the FAA. While I know the answer is yes, I don't know where in Title 14 the answer can be found. I've searched multiple resources for over two hours.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAA does not define the terms turboprop and turbojet in the FARs.  These terms are defined in the Pilots Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge.

- **Turbine engine.** An aircraft engine which consists of an air compressor, a combustion section, and a turbine. Thrust is produced by increasing the velocity of the air flowing
  through the engine.
- **Turbocharger.** An air compressor driven by exhaust gases, which increases the pressure of the air going into the engine through the carburetor or fuel injection system.
- **Turbofan engine.** A fanlike turbojet engine designed to create additional thrust by diverting a secondary airflow around the combustion chamber.
- **Turbojet engine.** A turbine engine which produces its thrust entirely by accelerating the air through the engine.
- **Turboprop engine.** A turbine engine which drives a propeller through a reduction gearing arrangement. Most of the energy in the exhaust gases is converted into torque, rather than using its acceleration to drive the aircraft.